# SharpGL (OpenGL in C#) Solar System - Camera position is Calculated Wrong

Tags: c#, opengl, camera, sharpgl

I am currently learning OpenGL and I am trying to write simple solar system application similar to the one in tutorial, yet for some reason camera behavior is really weird and I am not sure what is causing this. I want my camera to look at the sun, but all I am getting are some really weird angles of planets or nothing at all, it might not even be pure camera problem. Can somebody tell me what exactly I am doing wrong? I would appreciate some code. If someone is willing to help and prefer to check application instead of reading code here, link is added below.

The camera here will be as close to the tutorial as possible (FPS), but I got also dragging/scrolling system instead of this.

```
public class Camera
{
    private static float eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ;
    private static float centerX, centerY, centerZ;
    private const float movingSpeed = 0.3f;
    private const float rotationSpeed = 0.25f;
    private static double i, j, k;

    public static float Height { get; set; }
    public static float Slope { get; set; }

    public void InitCamera()
    {
        eyeX = 0f;
        eyeY = 15f;
        eyeZ = 25f;
        centerX = 0;
        centerY = 2;
        centerZ = 0;
        Look();
    }

    public void Look()
    {
        Gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.LoadIdentity();
        Gl.LookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    public void UpdateDirVector()
    {
        i = -Math.Sin(((double)Slope).ToRadians()); 
        j = Math.Sin(((double)Height).ToRadians());  
        k = Math.Cos(((double)Slope).ToRadians());     

        centerX = eyeX - (float)i;
        centerY = eyeY - (float)j;
        centerZ = eyeZ - (float)k;
    }

    public static void CenterMouse()
    {
        if (GlCenter == null)
            return;
        var pos = (Point) GlCenter;
        WinApi.SetCursorPos((int)Math.Round(pos.X), (int)Math.Round(pos.Y));
    }

    public void Update(int pressedButton)
    {
        if (GlCenter == null)
            return;
        var pos = (Point)GlCenter;
        var halfHeight = GlHeight / 2;
        var halfWidth = GlWidth / 2;

        var position = new Pointer();
        WinApi.GetCursorPos(ref position);

        var diffX = (float)pos.X - position.x;
        var diffY = (float)pos.Y - position.y;

        if (position.y < halfHeight)
            Height -= rotationSpeed * diffY;
        else if (position.y > halfHeight)
            Height += rotationSpeed * -diffY;
        if (position.x < halfWidth)
            Slope += rotationSpeed * -diffX;
        else if (position.x > halfWidth)
            Slope -= rotationSpeed * diffX;
        UpdateDirVector();
        CenterMouse();

        if (pressedButton == 1) // LPM
        {
            eyeX -= (float)i * movingSpeed;
            eyeY -= (float)j * movingSpeed;
            eyeZ -= (float)k * movingSpeed;
        }
        else if (pressedButton == -1) // PPM
        {
            eyeX += (float)i * movingSpeed;
            eyeY += (float)j * movingSpeed;
            eyeZ += (float)k * movingSpeed;
        }

        Look();
    }
}
```

Planet.cs:

```
public class Planet
{
    private readonly PlanetTypes _planetType;
    private readonly Position _position;
    private float _orbitAngle;
    private readonly float _sizeRadius;
    private readonly float _velocity;
    private readonly string _texturePath;

    private uint _list;
    private float _rotationAngle;

    public Planet(float radius, PlanetTypes planetType, Position position, string texturePath, bool hasMoon)
    {
        _sizeRadius = radius;
        _planetType = planetType;
        _position = position;
        _orbitAngle = Rng.Next(360);
        _velocity = (float)Rng.NextDouble() * 0.3f;
        _texturePath = texturePath;
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        var quadric = Gl.NewQuadric(); 
        Gl.QuadricNormals(quadric, OpenGL.GLU_SMOOTH);
        Gl.QuadricTexture(quadric, (int) OpenGL.GL_TRUE);

        _list = Gl.GenLists(1);
        Gl.NewList(_list, OpenGL.GL_COMPILE);
        Gl.PushMatrix();
        Gl.Rotate(270, 1, 0, 0);
        Gl.Sphere(quadric, _sizeRadius, 32, 32); 
        Gl.PopMatrix();
        Gl.EndList();
    }

    public void DrawOrbit()
    {
        Gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (var i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
            Gl.Vertex(_position.X * (float)Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180), 0, _position.X * (float)Math.Cos(i * Math.PI / 180));
        Gl.End(); 
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        DrawOrbit(); 

        LoadTexture($"{_texturesPath}{_texturePath}");

        Gl.PushMatrix();
        _orbitAngle += _velocity;
        _rotationAngle += 0.6f;
        Gl.Rotate(_orbitAngle, 0, 1, 0);
        Gl.Translate(-_position.X, -_position.Y, -_position.Z);

        Gl.Rotate(_rotationAngle, 0, 1, 0);

        Gl.CallList(_list);

        Gl.PopMatrix();
    } 
}
```

Sun.cs

```
public class Sun
{
    private uint _list;
    private float _rotation;
    private readonly string _texturePath;

    public Sun(string texturePath)
    {
        _texturePath = texturePath;
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        var quadratic = Gl.NewQuadric();
        Gl.QuadricNormals(quadratic, OpenGL.GLU_SMOOTH);
        Gl.QuadricTexture(quadratic, (int)OpenGL.GL_TRUE);

        _list = Gl.GenLists(1);
        Gl.NewList(_list, OpenGL.GL_COMPILE);
        Gl.PushMatrix();
        Gl.Rotate(90, 1, 0, 0);
        Gl.Sphere(quadratic, 3, 32, 32);
        Gl.PopMatrix();
        Gl.EndList();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        LoadTexture($"{_texturesPath}{_texturePath}");
        Gl.PushMatrix();
        _rotation += 0.05f;
        Gl.Rotate(_rotation, 0, 1, 0);
        Gl.CallList(_list);
        Gl.PopMatrix();
    } 
}
```

Stars.cs

```
public class Stars
{
    private readonly List<Position> starPositions = new List<Position>();

    public void CreateStars(int amount)
    {
        var count = 0;
        while (count <= amount)
        {
            var p = default(Position);
            p.X = Rng.Next(110) * (float)Math.Pow(-1, Rng.Next());
            p.Z = Rng.Next(110) * (float)Math.Pow(-1, Rng.Next());
            p.Y = Rng.Next(110) * (float)Math.Pow(-1, Rng.Next());

            if (!(Math.Pow(Math.Pow(p.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(p.Z, 2), 1 / 3f) > 15))
                continue;
            starPositions.Add(p);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_POINTS);
        Gl.Color(1, 1, 1);
        Gl.PointSize(3); 
        foreach (var starPos in starPositions)
            Gl.Vertex(starPos.X, starPos.Y, starPos.Z);   
        Gl.End(); 
    }
}
```

SolarSystem.cs (basically a collection of everything above, enums aren't necessary, I left them cause they might be useful in the future)

```
public class SolarSystem
{
    public static Random Rng { get; } = new Random();
    private readonly Stars _stars;
    private readonly Sun _sun;
    private readonly List<Planet> _planets;

    public SolarSystem()
    {
        Camera = new Camera();
        _stars = new Stars();
        _sun = new Sun("sun.bmp");
        _planets = new List<Planet>();
    }

    public void CreateScene()
    {
        _planets.Add(new Planet(0.5f, PlanetTypes.Mercury, new Position(5, 0, 0), "mercury.bmp", false)); // tylko tutaj pliki, wszedzie indziej przekształcone na .bmp
        _planets.Add(new Planet(0.7f, PlanetTypes.Venus, new Position(11, 0, 0), "venus.bmp", false));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1, PlanetTypes.Earth, new Position(15, 0, 0), "earth.bmp", true));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1, PlanetTypes.Mars, new Position(22, 0, 0), "mars.bmp", false));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1.5f, PlanetTypes.Jupiter, new Position(28, 0, 0), "jupiter.bmp", false));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1.2f, PlanetTypes.Saturn, new Position(35, 0, 0), "saturn.bmp", false));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1.2f, PlanetTypes.Uranus, new Position(41, 0, 0), "uranus.bmp", false));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1.2f, PlanetTypes.Neptune, new Position(51, 0, 0), "neptune.bmp", false));
        _planets.Add(new Planet(1.2f, PlanetTypes.Pluto, new Position(60, 0, 0), "pluto.bmp", false));
        _stars.CreateStars(500);
        _sun.Create();
        foreach (var planet in _planets)
            planet.Create();  
    }

    public Camera Camera { get; }

    public void DrawScene()
    {  
        _stars.Draw();
        _sun.Draw();
        foreach (var planet in _planets)
            planet.Draw();
    }

    public enum PlanetTypes
    {
        Mercury,
        Venus,
        Earth,
        Mars,
        Jupiter,
        Saturn,
        Neptune,
        Uranus,
        Pluto
    }
}
```

API (including pointer position translation, because only this way I was able to center cursor, it will be removed with dragging camera system)):

```
public static class WinApi
{
    [DllImport("GDI32.dll")]
    public static extern void SwapBuffers(uint hdc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void GetCursorPos(ref Pointer point);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    [DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "ClientToScreen", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ClientToScreen(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        ref POINT pt);

    [EnvironmentPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
    public static Point? TransformToScreen(
        Point point,
        Visual relativeTo)
    {
        var hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(relativeTo) as HwndSource;
        if (hwndSource == null)
            return null;
        var root = hwndSource.RootVisual;

        // Transform the point from the root to client coordinates.
        var transformToRoot = relativeTo.TransformToAncestor(root);
        var pointRoot = transformToRoot.Transform(point);
        var m = Matrix.Identity;
        var transform = VisualTreeHelper.GetTransform(root);
        if (transform != null)
        {
            m = Matrix.Multiply(m, transform.Value);
        }

        var offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(root);
        m.Translate(offset.X, offset.Y);
        var pointClient = m.Transform(pointRoot);
        pointClient = hwndSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform(pointClient);

        var pointClientPixels = new POINT();
        pointClientPixels.X = (0 < pointClient.X)
            ? (int)(pointClient.X + 0.5)
            : (int)(pointClient.X - 0.5);
        pointClientPixels.Y = (0 < pointClient.Y)
            ? (int)(pointClient.Y + 0.5)
            : (int)(pointClient.Y - 0.5);

        var pointScreenPixels = pointClientPixels;

        if (ClientToScreen(
            hwndSource.Handle,
            ref pointScreenPixels))
        {
            return new Point(
                pointScreenPixels.X,
                pointScreenPixels.Y);
        }
        return new Point();
    }
}
```

Extensions.cs

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double ToDegrees(this double radians)
    {
        return radians * (180.0 / Math.PI);
    }

    public static double ToRadians(this double degrees)
    {
        return Math.PI * degrees / 180.0;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;
    private uint _hdc;
    public static string _texturesPath = @"Data\Textures\";
    private SolarSystem _solarSystem;
    private int _movement;

    public static OpenGL Gl { get; private set; }
    public static Point? GlCenter { get; private set; }
    public static int GlHeight { get; private set; }
    public static int GlWidth { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
    }

    private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gl = openGLControl.OpenGL;

        var source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(openGLControl);
        var hWnd = source?.Handle;
        if (hWnd != null) _hdc = (uint)hWnd;

        _solarSystem = new SolarSystem();
        _solarSystem.Camera.InitCamera();

        float[] materialAmbient = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
        float[] materialDiffuse = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1.0f };
        float[] materialShininess = { 10.0f };
        float[] lightPosition = { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f };
        float[] lightAmbient = { 0.85f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 0.0f };

        Gl.Light(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0, OpenGL.GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);
        Gl.Light(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0, OpenGL.GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
        Gl.Material(OpenGL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, OpenGL.GL_SHININESS, materialShininess);
        Gl.Material(OpenGL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, OpenGL.GL_DIFFUSE, materialDiffuse);
        Gl.Material(OpenGL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, OpenGL.GL_AMBIENT, materialAmbient);

        Gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_LIGHTING);
        Gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0);
        Gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        _solarSystem.CreateScene();

        Gl.ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);


        GlCenter = WinApi.TransformToScreen(new Point(openGLControl.Width / 2, openGLControl.Height / 2), openGLControl);

        GlHeight = (int)openGLControl.Height;
        GlWidth = (int)openGLControl.Width;

        Camera.CenterMouse();

        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        _solarSystem.Camera.Update(_movement);
        _solarSystem.DrawScene();

        WinApi.SwapBuffers(_hdc);
        Gl.Flush();
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            _movement = 1;
        else
            _movement = -1;
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _movement = 0;
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.C)
        {
            GlCenter = WinApi.TransformToScreen(new Point(openGLControl.Width / 2, openGLControl.Height / 2), openGLControl); // new Point((int)(Left), (int)(Top));
        }
    }

    public static uint LoadTexture(string filename)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new ArgumentException(filename);

        Gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        var texture = new uint[1];
        var id = texture[0];
        Gl.GenTextures(1, texture);
        Gl.BindTexture(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

        var bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
        var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        Gl.TexImage2D(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, bmpData.Width, bmpData.Height, 0, OpenGL.GL_BGR, OpenGL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bmpData.Scan0);

        Gl.TexParameter(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, OpenGL.GL_LINEAR);
        Gl.TexParameter(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, OpenGL.GL_LINEAR);

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        return id;
    }
}
```

**Link to whole Application:**

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uhfyeayxn8l7q9y/AAA8tFda5-ZLAjTUzJcwKUm6a?dl=0

**UPDATE 1:**

I have changed Look() function to:

```
public void Look()
{
    Gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.LoadIdentity();
    Gl.Viewport(0, 0, GlWidth, GlHeight);
    Gl.Perspective(45.0f, GlWidth / (double) GlHeight, 1, 200.0);
    Gl.LookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, 0, 1, 0);
    Gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

And now it works.

Now I can see that my application is loading incorrect textures for some reason. I guess thats because method LoadTextures() I wrote, is using Gl.GenTextures(1, texture). (There is no Gen(Single)Texture method in sharpgl or I am getting it all wrong).

**UPDATE 2:**

So basically most of my textures doesn't work because they are not power of two, but from what I have read, they don't have to be anymore. SO my current question is: How to force sharpGL to display NPOT textures?

**UPDATE 3:**

Turns out I can load them like this, but well, they are upside down :).

```
_texture = new Texture();
...
Gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
_texture.Create(Gl, $"{_texturesPath}{_texturePath}");
_texture.Bind(Gl);
```

**UPDATE 4:**

I can flip texture to display it properly, but question is why this is happening?

```
Gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
var bmp = new Bitmap($"{_texturesPath}{_texturePath}");
bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
_texture.Create(Gl, bmp);
_texture.Bind(Gl);
```

**UPDATE 5:**

While question from Update 4 still stands, I got last question: How can I recalculate Camera so it is not limited to look up / down only to -90/90 degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be setting up your viewing frustrum correctly, and are using it in an uninitialized state. You have code for it, but it is commented out in MainWindow.xaml.cs:123.

You must setup the frustrum. At least once before drawing. It can be either perspective or orthographic.

```
gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.LoadIdentity();
gl.Perspective(60.0f, (double)Width / (double)Height, 0.01, 100.0);
```

Comment: I have actually figured it out too (updated code in my post) and it works now. Thank you very much. Now I just need to figure out why my application is loading incorrect textures.

Comment: .[NPOT](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/NPOT_Texture). On the version of GL you are using, textures indeed need to be ^2. Unsure which version of GL removed this, but certainly GL2 didn't support this, although there were extensions for specific vendors which removed this before it became a GL standard.

Comment: According to [SharpGL compatibility](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl/wiki/OpenGL-Compatibility), SharpGL does support NPOT textures and Rectangular Textures so you can use the GL_ARB_texture_rectangle and GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two extensions.

Comment: I figured how to load the textures, thanks sir, but am I missing something, why do you say sharpgl is using  opengl 2? isn't this written in specification: "SharpGL now supports OpenGL 4.3 completely."? Or am I completely missing something obvious here? Alright now I need to figure out why textures are upside down, I mean I can flip them but they shouldn't be like this.

Comment: I say version 2, since that's what sharpGL defaults to if you do not [specify a version](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl/wiki/Specifying-OpenGL-Version). Not all functions and abilities are available in all versions of GL, and some behave slightly different, not majorly, but you just need to be aware which version you are using. If you have come from a windows background, bitmaps and images are inverted in the y compared to GL as you have found out so I don't think anything is wrong there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you helped me a lot, thank you very much. I got problem with Camera Pitch to resolve but it is more out of curiosity cuz ultimately, I am going to adapt my drag/scroll system (and problebly will have the same problem with it anyway). Actually I am not new to .NET, but I am completely new to OpenGL, I am really struggling with c++ too comparing to c# which I know rather well. Thats why I decided to go with sharpgl....

Comment: ...Look at my code in Update 3, thats what confused me because methods defined for Texture type are coming straight from sharpGL. You are right, textures are upside down when loaded using new Bitmap from System.Drawing, but they are upside down as well when loaded using Texture methods.

Comment: OpenGL assumes the origin of a texture (0,0) is bottom left of an image. Windows assumes the origin of an image is top left. Hence the flip to display an OpenGL texture the same as windows bitmap (or vice versa). :)